# Stancl/tenancy: How to store files for specific tenant?

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I was using image/intervention package to upload files and store.
and for this package I store files lik

```
$img = Image::make($imageFile);
$img->save($full_path.$filename);
```

But now, using tenancy, the files are stored and can be access globally, I want to store files tenant specific. How to do it?
As per the Stancl/tenancy doc.

```
Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, $data);
```

can help. But it is not working.